# Transform grammar into LL(1), identify whether it is LL(1)

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, automata, formal-languages

I cannot quite understand how to determine whether grammar is LL(1) or not. I have been given the following grammar:

```
S → Y | 1X 
X → 1X | 0
Y → Y0|1X1|2X2
```

I stated that this grammar is not LL(1) because it Y0 is left recursive.

So I came up with the following solution:

```
S → Y | 1X
X → 1X | 0
Y → 1X1F | 2X2F
F → ε | 0F
```

But still I am not sure if that is correct. I still think that I must have missed some rule like factoring of some sort. Would I have to take 1X and 2X into different variable?

Thanks for help in advance. I would also like to know if there are easier ways to determine whether the grammar is LL(1) I have came across a lot of "first" and "follow" tables, but haven't actually managed to build one myself.

Answer (score 1):

If factor our 1X then I get the following:

```
S → Y | Z
X → Z | 0
Y → Z1F | 2X2F
F → ε | 0F
Z → 1X | ε
```

Which means that S → Y | Z and I believe that is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

An LL(1) grammar needs to be able to predict a production based on a single (`(1)`) lookahead token. However, both `Y` and `1X` can start with `1`, so it is impossible to predict whether to use `S→Y` or `S→1X` given the first input symbol `1`. So neither the original grammar nor the transformed grammar are LL(1).

Comment: Will I have to factor 1X out into another variable like this?: 

`S → Y | 1X
X → Z | 0
Y → Z1F | 2X2F
F → ε | 0F
Z → 1X |  ε`

Comment: @AlenEviLL: Does that deal with the problem indicated in this answer? You will certainly have to do some factoring...

Comment: Help please I am stuck, see my answer, I am even going the right way? @rici